# PL/SQL embedding SELECT into function

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to embed a simple SELECT statement inside of a stored function, but it seems to be throwing these errors:

> SQL Statement Ignored (line 9)

and

> Missing left parenthesis (line 12)

First off, why is it ignoring my select statement?
And second off, I have no parentheses on line 12, so I don't understand how that error is even being thrown.

But here is my stored function code nonetheless:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tax_calc_sf
(p_basketid IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  lv_taxamt_num NUMBER;
  lv_subtotal_num bb_basket.subtotal%TYPE;
  lv_taxrate_num bb_tax.taxrate%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT bb.subtotal, bt.taxrate
  INTO lv_subtotal_num, lv_taxrate_num
  FROM bb_basket bb
  JOIN bb_tax bt USING bt.state = bb.shipstate
  WHERE bb.idbasket = p_basketid;

  lv_taxamt_num := lv_subtotal_num*lv_taxrate_num;
  RETURN lv_taxamt_num;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ON bt.state = bb.shipstate
```

instead of

```
USING bt.state = bb.shipstate
```

The error `Missing left parantheses` is thrown precisly *because* there are no parantheses. The `USING` clause requires parantheses. It also requires the join column to be named equally in both tables. Since this is not the case in your tables, you must use the `ON` clause.

Comment: Wow what a silly mistake. xDDD I can't believe I did that :P I had using to begin with, but then I had to change it and forgot to change that. Thanks.. just needed another pair of eyes I guess